# DataFrame with JSON column: Export to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, to-json

I have a Pandas dataframe with a JSON formatted column, on export of the whole DF as JSON, the JSON column will be formatted like a normal string:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b': ['a','b', 'c','d']})

foo['json'] = foo.apply(lambda x: x[['b']].to_json(), axis=1)

OUTPUT:
   a  b       json
0  1  a  {"b":"a"}
1  2  b  {"b":"b"}
2  3  c  {"b":"c"}
3  4  d  {"b":"d"}
```

```
foo.to_json()

OUTPUT:

{"a":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4},"b":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d"},"json":{"0":"{\"b\":\"a\"}","1":"{\"b\":\"b\"}","2":"{\"b\":\"c\"}","3":"{\"b\":\"d\"}"}}
```

How can I export this without the forward slashes?

Comment: Why do you care about the slashes? they merely escape the quotes. What are you going to do with the output of `to_json`? It is most likely that they won't cause any issue

Comment: The Output will be exported into a MongoDB, I am concerned this is not really a clean json output :(

(thanks for your fast answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to apply `to_dict()`, which is the most native pandas method, although I´m not absolutely sure if its the most performant way.

```
foo.to_json()


OUTPUT:

'{"a":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4},"b":{"0":"a","1":"b","2":"c","3":"d"},"json":{"0":{"b":"a"},"1":{"b":"b"},"2":{"b":"c"},"3":{"b":"d"}}}'
```